# Why isn't natsort (or natcasesort) working here?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, natsort

Perhaps I'm doing something embarrassingly wrong, but why isn't this array being sorted?

```
$narray=array();

$dir_handle = @opendir($path.$projectFolder) or die("Unable to open $path$projectFolder");

$i=0;

while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

 $filenameSplit = explode('.',$file);

 if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $filenameSplit[0] != "logo" && $filenameSplit[1] != "zip" && $filenameSplit[1] != "pdf" && $filenameSplit[1] != "doc" && $filenameSplit[1] != "psd" && $filenameSplit[1] != "") {

  $narray[$i]=$file;

  $i++;
 }

}

natcasesort($narray);
```

I seem to be getting the same results I get when I don't attempt to sort the array at all. `sort()` works, but nothing else seems to.

Thanks for any help!

---

Update:

Here are sample results:

With *no sort*:

```
03_piper_file-manager_02.jpg
05_piper_login-page_02.jpg
02_piper_file-manager_no-slides_01.jpg
04_piper_file-manager_02.jpg
01_piper_file-manager_no-slides_01.jpg
```

With `sort()`:

```
01_piper_file-manager_no-slides_01.jpg
02_piper_file-manager_no-slides_01.jpg
03_piper_file-manager_02.jpg
04_piper_file-manager_02.jpg
05_piper_login-page_02.jpg
```

With `natsort()` or `natcasesort()`:

```
03_piper_file-manager_02.jpg
05_piper_login-page_02.jpg
02_piper_file-manager_no-slides_01.jpg
04_piper_file-manager_02.jpg
01_piper_file-manager_no-slides_01.jpg
```

I expect at the very least for natsort's results to look like sort's.

Comment: Maybe the array is already sorted? The results are usually in alphabetical order anyways, although it is OS dependant.

Comment: Can you show us what kind of result you get with `natcasesort`, and what you expect instead?

Comment: Do you have some sample data in mind? Or, given some setup of $narray, what are you getting and what do you expect to get?

Comment: I've added some sample results to my post. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ElLDQu

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the return value of natcasesort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`natcasesort` maintains the key/value relationship, so if you are iterating over the array with an index, you will see this behavior.

Try `print_r($narray)` after `natcasesort`.  You can iterate the array using foreach.

```
foreach ($narray as $elem)
{
   /* operate on $elem */
}
```

Comment: `print_r` after `natcasesort` gives me this:

`Array ( [4] => 01_piper_file-manager_no-slides_01.jpg [2] => 02_piper_file-manager_no-slides_01.jpg [0] => 03_piper_file-manager_02.jpg [3] => 04_piper_file-manager_02.jpg [1] => 05_piper_login-page_02.jpg`
  
I'm not experienced enough to know what to make of it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Tim Call `array_values` before iterating or iterate with `foreach` instead.

Comment: I updated my answer to tell you how to iterate over the array in order.

Comment: I have a for loop that looks like this:

`for($i=0; $i<sizeof($narray); $i++)`

Comment: @Tim: Change that for loop to the foreach listed in my answer, and use "$elem" instead of "$narray[$i]" - you will be set.

Comment: @Tim: A plain for loop will not access the elements in order as they are in the array. It will access them by the value of the key (i.e. in their original order).

Comment: @felix exactly, that was my problem.