# PHP can I do this loop?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have a loop (based on an array - which could grow but NOT too much - max 6 keys) e.g.: `array('12','34','56',48')`.  What I would like to do is loop through the array and THEN loop again to find the "previous" array val.

For example, `key[0] = 12`, `key[1] = 34` then `key[0] = 12`, `key[2] = 56` then `key[1] = 34` etc.

The values of the array are ID's from a DB and I need (hopefully) to run a query based on the "current key" and the previous key.

Any ideas - can it be done?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of arrays. Or you have not described your problem well enough.

Comment: Can you expound more on your example of what you are looking for?  For example spell it out in 2 loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think multiple loops are really needed here.  I would use the internal pointer of the array with [`next()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), [`prev()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php), and [`current()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
$num_elem = count($array); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_elem; $i++)
{
   $curr_val = $array[$i];
   $prev_val = ( 0 == $i) ? null: $array[$i-1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the other solutions, I would recommend **against** using an index based accessor.

In php, the keys are not necessarily in order.  For example, if you call `natsort` on your array, the `key=>value` relationships stay the same but the array itself is actually reordered, leading to counterintuitive results.  (See [Why isn't natsort (or natcasesort) working here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398773/why-isnt-natsort-or-natcasesort-working-here))

I would use something like:

```
<?php
  $ids = array('12','34','56','48');
  $previous = false;
  foreach($ids as $id)
  {
    echo "current: $id\n";
    echo "previous: $previous\n";
    $previous = $id;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you want to do this.

```
for($i=1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  $currentValue = $array[$i];
  $previousValue = $array[$i-1];

  // Here you can run a query based on the current and the previous value
}
```

For example, taking `$array` as `array(12,34,56,48)` you would have 3 iterations where the `$currentValue` and `$previousValue` would have the following values:

1. First iteration: $currentValue = 34, $previousValue = 12
2. Second iteration: $currentValue = 56, $previousValue = 34
3. Third iteration: $currentValue = 48, $previousValue = 56

Comment: With the above you would miss using the zero index for the current value - which could prevent some needed action.

Comment: If the requirement is to do a query with the current and the previous value than it has to start with the second item otherwise the previous value would not exist. Anyway I understand that this depends on the specific behavior required and I supposed the one I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$val = 56;
$data = array(12, 34, 12, 56, 34);
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
  if($data[$i] == $val) {
    if($i == 0) die("No previous");
    $previous = $data[$i-1];
  }
}

echo "Previous to $val was $previous";
```

or better yet use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)()
to find index for given $val